# What is the recommended structure for writing a list of integers on XML?

Tags: python, xml

I have a list of integers [22,23,64,65,9] and what is the best way to store it over an xml file

```
<cls>
  <cl value="22" />
  <cl value="23" />
  <cl value="64" />
  <cl value="65" />
  <cl value="9" />
</cls>
```

I now have the above structure and is it advisable to use the same ? my end goal is to parse it back to python list.

Comment: nothing's critical in your structure, you may use it

Comment: do you really need xml? because `json` would be so much readable and easy.

Comment: Looks OK to me. What to the tags represent? Are `cls` and `cl` good names? JSON would be easier to work with, if that is an option for you.

Comment: My application deals only with xml. But what if I set the list like <cls>22,23,64,65,9</cls> ? is it advisable too ?

Comment: if you do this, you'll have to perform a `split` afterwards. Looks that you're inventing your own sub-format then

Comment: Thanks, but which is the best method ? recommended one. In terms of memory and speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet is all right, but something like

```
<cls>22,23,64,65,9</cls>
```

would be OK and faster if parsed by python like this:

```
[int(x) for x in xml_string.split(",")]
```

because the xml parser has less work to iterate on the nodes. The "all in one" approach is shorter in bytes (because you don't need `<cl value="" />` so the data is way smaller, particularly on a big list), and thus consumes less resources (always time various approaches).

The only issues I'm seeing:

- you're creating a custom sub-format to xml
- if you're trying to do the same with strings, and they contain commas, you're back to square one: in that case, leave the list to xml parser.
- if you were doing that in C, that would require much more code like `strtok` to parse, and a lot of tedious string operations to create. So if you share your format with a C program, the C coder will hate you for this :)